# Issue in searching a name in entity framework model using code first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have the following code to retrieve a name when a user enters the name in the search box and the function searches the name from Student model. Please find below the code. However, it doesn't show anything.

```
      public Student SearchName(string search)
        {
            var student = _context.Student.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == search);
            var student = from a in _context.Student
                            select a;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
               student = student.Where(a => a.Name!.Contains(search))
            }
            return student;
        }
```